# map each array value of enum to enum value

Tags: java, java-8

I've got enum that looks like this

```
public enum ContainerEnum {
    CONTAINER_1(new ElementTypeEnum[] {
        ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_1,
        ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_2
    }),
    CONTAINER_2(new ElementTypeEnum[] {
        ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_3,
        ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_4
    });
    ....
}
```

All `ElementTypeEnum` items are unique for each `Container` element.

Now I have an array of possible containers

```
ContainerEnum[] containers = ContainerEnum.values();
```

But how to map each `ElementTypeEnum` entry to each `ContainerEnum` key? I mean to get pairs like this

```
{ ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_1, CONTAINER_1 },
{ ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_2, CONTAINER_1 },
{ ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_3, CONTAINER_2 },
{ ElementTypeEnum.TYPE_4, CONTAINER_2 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EnumSet.allOf(ContainerEnum.class)
       .stream()
       .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.getElementTypeEnums()).map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

assuming something like a getter `getElementTypeEnums()` exists.

Comment: what is the difference between `EnumSet.allOf` and `Arrays.stream(enum.values())`?

Comment: @lapots for your concrete example, none really.